# Unable to change android default launcher icon in android studio 2.2 preview 4

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-studio-2.2

I have changed android app's icon by copying the 'res' folder generated from the https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

But recently I updated my android studio to 2.2 preview 4 . When I changed the app icon by following the same procedure mentioned above,the icon is not changing some how it still the default android icon

The things I tried are

1. Searched for ic_launcher.png in the res folder and make sure that there is no other file than the custom one I made.
2. Restarted the project.

Comment: one of your drawable folder have old ic_launcher image......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I renamed my ic_launcher.png to ic_launcher1.png

Answer (score 0):

Either you find all the images of ic_launcher in mipmap if using android studio or in drawable if using eclipse or also you can go inside manifest file and change app icon from application tag named as icon

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you can change here in your application tag

```
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Answer (score 0):

to add your image into res folder go to mipmap open it with click go to Image Asset and select there image and select it from its location, go to image location and then select it, just added the image on res folder and selected its on of type from xxxhdpi.png, xxhdpi.png xhdpi.png hdpi.png.. I selected hdpi.png from that
And then go to  AndroidManifest.xml and change ic_launcher to your selected image type or press ctrl+space you will get all the option you have

(android:icon="@mipmap/hdpi" )